# Getting 'TypeError: win.matchMedia is not a function' when i try to start ionic app with SSR in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, server-side-rendering

I have ionic PWA application with SSR. When i try to start 'dev:ssr' i've got "TypeError: win.matchMedia is not a function".

`const isPWA = (win) => !!(win.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches || win.navigator.standalone);`

this row inside server/main.js file

Comment: What's win? An alias for window? Since this is SSR you might need to check that window exists

Comment: But it's not in my source code, i can't check it

Comment: isPWA is not being passed the correct argument. this function expects it is being passed `window` as a param. 

perhaps you're passing the wrong argument or your app does not have `window` for some scope issue. not familiar with ionic framework :(

Comment: @ТарасКравец did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, I think I found the solution to this error: components running on Server side cannot contain ngAfterViewInit, ionViewWillEnter and others. In my case it was giving error with ionic 5 / angular 10